# Does the Chimera respawn once it's been killed?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

The Chimera's one of the new Heartless that spawn at the manor in Halloween Town, later on in the game. I've fought it once and I've heard that it is the only way you can get Blazing Stones in the game. I'm wondering if it's farmable for Blazing Stones, or if it's just a one-time Heartless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that Chimera was a special boss this entire time. It's farmable (and the easiest way to determine whether it's spawning at the Manor IMO is to see if there's a red trinity mark on the arch at the bottom--if there is, it's not going to spawn, and if there isn't, it'll spawn).

Comment: Just going through my first 1.5 playthrough today and the thing about the trinity mark is wrong.  I hadn't used it yet, so I saw it there, but Chimera spawned.